# Getting NullReferenceException creating SqlConnection in .NET web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am getting a `System.NullReferenceException` exception in my web application:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
Home..ctor() in D:\Hosting\9651310\html\Home.aspx.vb:6
ASP.home_aspx..ctor() in D:\Hosting\9651310\html\Home.aspx.vb:912304
__ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_2ocmh1tt.Create_ASP_home_aspx() +47
System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance() +32
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp) +109
System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +31
System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path) +37
System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +334
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Here's the line that throws the exception:

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Connection").ToString())
```

The connection strings section of my web.config file looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: `Home.aspx.vb:6`.  That's a line number in your code.

Comment: I already gave the code in last line : Dim con As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Connection").ToString())

Comment: look into your web.config and check that a section like `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Connection" connectionString=...` is there. If it's not, add your connection string.

Comment: It's already there : 
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: your code is looking for `name="Connection"`, but you have a `name="ApplicationServices"`

Comment: Ohh thanks it worked :) i was unable to find that.

Comment: no worries... take a look at how @StevenDoggart modified your question and try to use a similar format for your next questions: that will increase your chances of getting good answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong name for your connection string.  Change the following line:

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Connection").ToString())
```

To this:

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ApplicationServices").ToString())
```